# Declaring delegates on .m

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am relatively new to Objective-C.

I have come to a code on the web that has something like this on rootViewController.m (this is a navigationController based app).

```
@interface RootViewController (CManagerDelegate) <CManagerDelegate>
@end

@interface RootViewController (PViewDelegate) <PViewDelegate>
@end
```

two questions:

1. what are these lines doing in the beginning of rootViewController.m
2. what are these lines doing in code? Please explain the stuff in parenthesis and between <> in this particular case.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one sentence: The code you posted makes the `RootViewController` class privately conform to some delegate protocols.

Delegate protocols are used to let a class declare the fact that it understands the messages from another class's objects. For example, a view controller can declare that it understands a gesture recognizer's delegate messages.

The fact that the class internally uses the gesture recognizer is often an implementation detail not relevant to other clients of the class. It is best not to publish this fact in the public interface but put it into the implementation (.m file).

Categories (and class extensions) let you do exactly this: Make a class conform to a protocol without changing the main `@interface`.

A nice and elegant solution!

Comment: ok, but what I don't get is this. If the declaration was without the parenthesis part, I would understand that a delegate protocol was being assigned to the class, but the parenthesis part sounds like an extension to the class. The question is how a class can be extended if the declaration in question is inside the implementation of the same class itself. This sounds insane and my brain is not absorbing all nutrients contained in that statement. Another question is this: why to make a class conform to a protocol privately? Is it a secret or something? :D

Comment: ah, and another thing is this, there's absolute nothing between the declaration and the @end... just the lines as I put on my question.

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper: This isn't inside the `@implementation`; it's usually immediately before it. The .h/.m thing is just convention (indeed, the compiler does not care about .h files at all, which is why you have to tell it to look at them with `#import`). A class's `@interface` can be extended at any point after the compiler sees the original `@interface`.

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper: Regarding the privacy of the category: The question is not whether it should be private; the question is whether it should be public. There generally is no reason to make the fact of the class's conformance to the protocol public; therefore, it should be private. And yes, you don't need anything between `@interface Foo` and `@end`. You aren't required to add anything of your own, and in this case, the contents of the protocol are everything you're declaring.

Comment: thanks but you guys have not explained what the parenthesis part is doing... :)

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper You should just read the documentation. Sanjay Chaudhry provided the necessary links in his answer.

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper: The “parenthesis part” makes this a category. The name of the category is within the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on Categories:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

And Protocols:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/ocProtocols.html

In fact, read all of Apple's Objective-c documentation before going any further:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Good luck.